# PHP script failing to get post data from javascript/sql update query fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, post

So I have a php script running on our server to put data into our database. I want it to handle two different scenarios: Add a new entry, or update an existing entry. I have:

```
$update = $_POST['Update'];

if('$update' == '0'){
$squareN = $_POST['SquareN'];
printf("N: %f\n", $squareN);
$squareE = $_POST['SquareE'];
printf("E: %f\n", $squareE);
$squareS = $_POST['SquareS'];
printf("S: %f\n", $squareS);
$squareW = $_POST['SquareW'];
printf("W: %f\n", $squareW);
$siteName = $_POST['SiteName'];
printf("Name: %s\n", $siteName);
$siteType = $_POST['SiteType'];
printf("Type: %d\n", $siteType);
$estFlags = $_POST['EstFlags'];
printf("Flags: %d\n", $estFlags);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `dec1620_db`.`Sites` (`SiteID`, `SiteName`, `CircleLat`, `CircleLon`, `CircleRad`, `SquareN`, `SquareE`, `SquareS`, `SquareW`, `Active`, `SiteType`, `EstFlags`) VALUES (NULL, '$siteName', NULL, NULL, NULL, '$squareN', '$squareE', '$squareS', '$squareW', 1, '$siteType', '$estFlags')";

mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
if('$update' == '1'){
$squareN = $_POST['SquareN'];
printf("N: %f\n", $squareN);
$squareE = $_POST['SquareE'];
printf("E: %f\n", $squareE);
$squareS = $_POST['SquareS'];
printf("S: %f\n", $squareS);
$squareW = $_POST['SquareW'];
printf("W: %f\n", $squareW);
$siteName = $_POST['SiteName'];
printf("Name: %s\n", $siteName);

$sql = "UPDATE `Sites` SET `SquareN`='$squareN', `SquareE`='$squareE', `SquareS`='$squareS', `SquareW`='$squareW' WHERE `SiteName`='$siteName';

mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

But $update = $_POST['Update'] kills the script with a 500 error. I have error reporting turned on, and an alert set up in my post to print data/errors, but I get nothing when the error happens... I am not sure why the $update = $_POST['Update'] fails, but all other ones succeed in grabbing correct data. Where update == 0, if I take out update and if statements and update == 1 part, that works perfectly fine when I add a new google map rectangle. When I take out update and if statement and update == 0 part and try to edit bounds of a rectangle the script errors out, again with no report of the actual error.

my posts are:

```
$.post("send_jobsite.php", {
       'Update': 1,
       'SquareN': rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat,
       'SquareE': rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng,
       'SquareS': rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat,
       'SquareW': rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng,
       'SiteName': rectangle.id
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert("Server Response: " + data);
    });

$.post("send_jobsite.php", {
    'Update': 0,
    'SquareN': rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat,
    'SquareE': rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng,
    'SquareS': rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat,
    'SquareW': rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng,
    'SiteName': $("#jobname").val(),
    'SiteType': 3,
    'EstFlags': $("#numberFlags").val()
    }).done(function(data) {
    alert("Server Response: " + data);
    });
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Try using `if(isset($_POST['Update'])) { }` to double check if this POST variable is set or not. Besides, this won't cause error but I feel that `$_POST['Update'] == 1` vs `$_POST['Update'] == '1'` can give you different results

Comment: But there is apparently something wrong with my UPDATE query as well. Everything I have read says that is how you perform an update query in php... but it doesn't work. I have tried with and without the back ticks on the column names too with no luck.

Comment: And $_POST['Update'] completely fails. I have no idea why when all the other $_POST's work perfectly fine....

Comment: "there is apparently something wrong with my UPDATE query as well" good, then delete it and write a prepared statement

Comment: What would be a prepared statement? I need to update those values in my mysql database. I am not sure what the correct statement to do this is as mine is apparently wrong. (And I am aware of sql injections, I have not gotten around to taking care of them yet, the user can only enter name and estimated number of flags, so those are the only ones that need protection).